# How to redirect if page name contains column

Tags: iis

I have couple external links to my website that look like www.sitename.com/pagename.asphttp://www.sitename.com/pagename.asp . Someone obviously made a mistake when posting these.

What I'm trying to do now is to redirect such URL to www.sitename.com/pagename.asp. So far I've tried associating  .asphttp files with DLL used for processing ASP pages but I still have the problem because of the : character.

So basically, my question is how to redirect www.sitename.com/pagename.asp: to www.sitename.com/pagename.asp (without the column at the end)

Answer (score 1):

If you know ASP or ASP.NET, you could build a page that catches these mistakes and does a re-direct to the correct page.  Then you could configure IIS to use this page for the 404 page.

Here is an example project that has similar code and shows the IIS configs:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18262/Using-HttpModules-with-URL-Re-writing-to-Handle-Fa

I would probably alter the code so it replaced ".asphttp://" with ".asp?", within the original URL.  It would make things simpler.